# Jsoup - parsing data from table in Java

Tags: java, parsing, jsoup

I'm trying to make a parser to get the latest SQL versions that have appeared (build version only).
He receives an error, and additional text he doesn't need.
What am I doing wrong?

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://buildnumbers.wordpress.com/sqlserver/").get();
Elements trs = doc.select("tr");

//remove header row
trs.remove(0);

for (Element tr : trs) {
            Elements tds = tr.getElementsByTag("td");
            Element td = tds.last();
            System.out.println(td.text());
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [String::substring](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-) to get rid of `(...)` at the end of each text. Also, you have missed `null` check everywhere in your program.

Do it as follows:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://buildnumbers.wordpress.com/sqlserver/").get();
        Elements trs = doc.select("tr");

        // remove header row
        trs.remove(0);

        String text;
        int i;
        for (Element tr : trs) {
            Elements tds = tr.getElementsByTag("td");
            Element td;
            if (tds != null) {
                td = tds.last();
                if (td != null) {
                    text = td.text();
                    if (text != null) {
                        i = text.indexOf("(");
                        if (i != -1) {
                            System.out.println(text.substring(0, i).trim());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
15.0.4013.40
14.0.3281.6
13.0.5698.0
...
...
...
SSMS 16.4
SSMS 16.3
```

Comment: This solution doesn't show: 15.0.4013.40, 14.0.3281.6 result, why?

Comment: @Ebasse - the content of the website has changed and now you will see `13.0.5698.0  
12.0.6372.1 ...`. Just access the URL https://buildnumbers.wordpress.com/sqlserver/ in your browser and you will understand it.

Answer (score 0):

**additional text**

Your problem doesn't have to do anything with Jsoup. It extracted the values exactly as in table cells and it can't help you anymore.
You can now try to remove the text you don't want using substring, so replace the line

```
System.out.println(td.text());
```

with this code:

```
String text = td.text();
if (text.contains("(")) {
    text = text.substring(0, text.indexOf("(")-1);
}
System.out.println(text);
```

It will keep only the text before `(` character.

**NullPointerException**

The page you're parsing contains many tables. You execute `doc.select("tr")` and that means your `trs` variable contains every `tr` of every table on this page. The exception occurs when your code encounters second table with header row that doesn't contain any `td` because it look like this:

```
<tr>
   <th style="padding:4px;background-color:#f0f0f0;width:10%;">SQL Server</th>
   <th style="padding:4px;background-color:#f0f0f0;width:10%;">Analysis Services</th>
   <th style="padding:4px;background-color:#f0f0f0;width:65%;">Description</th>
   <th style="padding:4px;background-color:#f0f0f0;width:15%;">Release Date</th>
</tr>
```

The solution would be to limit selection to only the first table, so replace line:

```
Elements trs = doc.select("tr");
```

with

```
Element firstTable = doc.select("table").first();
Elements trs = firstTable.select("tr");
```